# Accessing SQLite DB /w python and getting malformed DBs

Tags: python, sqlite, ssh, sftp

I have some python code that copies a SQLite db across sftp. However, it is a highly active db, so many of the times I am running into a malformed db. I'm thinking of these possible options, but I don't know how to implement them because I am newer to python.

- Alternate method of getting the sqlite db copied?
- Maybe there is a way to query the sqlite file from the device? Not sure if that would work since sqlite is more of a local db not sure how I can query it like I could w mysql etc...
- Create a loop? I could call the function again in the exception, but not sure how to retry the rest of the code.
- Also, the malformed db issue can possibly occur in other sections im thinking? Maybe I need to run a pragma quick_check?

This is commonly what I am seeing.... The other catch is why am I seeing it as often as I am? Because if I load the sqlite file from my main machine, and it runs the query files?

[image: pragma]

[image: query]

```
(venv) dulanic@mediaserver:/opt/python_scripts/rpi$  cd /opt/python_scripts/rpi ; /usr/bin/env /opt/python_scripts/rpi/venv/bin/python /home/dulanic/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.636928669/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 37599 -- /opt/python_scripts/rpi/rpdb.py 
An error occurred: database disk image is malformed
```

This is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import psycopg2, sqlite3, sys, paramiko, sys, os, socket, time 

scpuser=os.getenv('scpuser')
scppw = os.getenv('scppw')
sqdb = os.getenv('sqdb')
sqlike = os.getenv('sqlike')
pgdb = os.getenv('pgdb')
pguser = os.getenv('pguser')
pgpswd = os.getenv('pgpswd')
pghost = os.getenv('pghost')
pgport = os.getenv('pgport')
pgschema = os.getenv('pgschema')
database = r"./pihole.db"
pihole = socket.gethostbyname('pi.hole')
tabnames=[]
tabgrab = ''

def pullsqlite(): 
    sftp.get('/etc/pihole/pihole-FTL.db','pihole.db')
    sftp.close()

# SFTP pull config
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=pihole,username=scpuser,password=scppw)
sftp=ssh_client.open_sftp()

# Pull SQlite
pullsqlite()

# Load sqlite tables to list
consq=sqlite3.connect(sqdb)
cursq=consq.cursor()    
cursq.execute(f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name in ({sqlike})" )
tabgrab = cursq.fetchall()

# postgres connection
conpg = psycopg2.connect(database=pgdb, user=pguser, password=pgpswd,
                        host=pghost, port=pgport)

#Load data to postgres from sqlite

for item in tabgrab:
    tabnames.append(item[0])
    start = time.perf_counter() 

for table in tabnames:
    curpg = conpg.cursor()
    if table=='queries':
        curpg.execute(f"SELECT max(id)  FROM {table};")
        max_id = curpg.fetchone()[0]
        cursq.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table} where id > {max_id};")
    else:
        cursq.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table};")
    try:     
        rows=cursq.fetchall()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])

    colcount=len(rows[0])
    pholder=('%s,'*colcount)[:-1]
 
    try:
 
        curpg.execute(f"SET search_path TO {pgschema};" )
        curpg.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES ({pholder}) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;" ,rows)
        conpg.commit()
        print(f'Inserted {len(rows)} rows into {table}')
 
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        print (f'Error {e}') 
        sys.exit(1)

if 'start' in locals():
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f'Time {elapsed:0.4}')
consq.close()
```

Comment: Oops, copying a live SQLite DB is somewhere between *brave* and *foolish*. AFAIK, the only foolproof way is to use the [backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html#sqlite3backupinit) to produce a local copy and then download or upload that copy.

Comment: I agree it prob wasn't the best bet, but wasn't sure how else to do it. Because the python code will run on a different PC, I was having trouble identifying how to run the backup first across ssh.Thinking this over.... I could run a cron job on the other device every say hour and just update from that. Seems like a bandaid workaround, but guess it could work.